# Why do C programmers often declare the "counter" variable outside the for loop condition:

Tags: c

I am new to C, and I presume that it makes no difference no matter how one does it, but I've noticed that in most examples for loops in see are written like in the following example:

```
int i;
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
   //some code
}
```

Rather then how I've initially been introduced to for loops in Java:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    //some code
}
```

Is there any reason behind this in C?

Comment: The ability to declare the variable in the loop control expression is relatively new, introduced in the 1999 standard.  Anyone who programmed in C before then *had* to declare the variable outside of the loop.  That style has persisted in a lot of examples (which were either written before 1999, or by people who learned C before 1999).

Comment: Declaring it outside the loop allows it to be used after the loop is done. You can check the value to find out if the loop stopped because of some break statement or it finished by reaching the conditional counter.

Answer (score 17):

1. Old c standards didn't allow to declare variables in the `for` and thus many programmers are used to it, and others simply are restricted to pre C99([c99](/questions/tagged/c99)) standard.

   But young c programmers like myself would write `for (int counter ...`, often even constructs like

   ```
    for (int index = 0; string[index] != '\0'; ++index) ...
   ```
2. Sometimes, it's just because the algorithm requries it. For instance if you need to know what the last value of `index` was in the example construct above. Which is a common way to traverse string characters.

Comment: `size_t` would be better for the loop variable in your example.